# Postgres table partition by list limit

Tags: postgresql, ddl, database-partitioning

I wonder if there is a limit for partition table by list where each subpartition table contains only one element.

For example, I have this partition table:

```
CREATE TABLE whatever (
    city_id         int not null,
    country_id      int not null,
) PARTITION BY LIST (country_id);
```

And I create millions of subpartition tables:

```
CREATE TABLE whatever_1 PARTITION OF whatever
    FOR VALUES IN (1);

CREATE TABLE whatever_2 PARTITION OF whatever
    FOR VALUES IN (2);

# until millions...

CREATE TABLE whatever_10000000 PARTITION OF whatever
    FOR VALUES IN (10000000);
```

Assuming an index on `country_id`, would that still work?
Or Will I hit the 65000 limit as described [here](https://twitter.com/jer_s/status/1258483727362953216)?

Comment: "*Millions of partitions*" are hardly sensible to begin with. What are you trying to achieve with that partitioning scheme? And which universe are you modeling where you have _millions_ of countries? The earth currently has about 200 countries.

Comment: This is just an example. Do not take care of this

Comment: Reading your description it seems you are using a sequence for country_id and then thinking you need a partition for sequence value. In addition to being basically a bad idea, it is also incorrect. Instead of an arbitrary assigned value use the [ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) standard.  In this case just load the entire list of countries . There are several candidate keys listed perhaps the best for here being *ISO 1366-1 Numeric Code*. Then create your partitions based on that giving  you  249 partitions not *millions*.

Comment: Country is an example... I'm not using country in real life. Assume it can be just an ID

Comment: Why partition at all? An index on `country_id` seems the better choice here.

Comment: No it's not...
With 100 millions of records and a query including conditions on a date for example, the index on date will be chosen over the country one.

Answer (score 1):

Even with PostgreSQL v13, anything that goes beyond at most a few thousand partitions won't work well, and it's better to stay lower.

The reason is that when you use a partitioned table in an SQL statement, the optimizer has to consider all partitions separately. It has to figure out which of the partitions it has to use and which not, and for all partitions that it uses it has to come up with an execution plan. Consequently, planning time will go up as the number of partitions increases. This may not matter for large analytical queries, where execution time dominates, but it will considerably slow down the execution of small statements.

Use longer lists or use range partitioning.

Comment: Yes; I have extended the answer to explain that.